# Committing a component in the vuex

Tags: vuejs2, vuex

My vue app has a sidebar, i want to display a component as its child.

I am trying to pass the component by committing it using a vuex store, but it seems not working.

I am using `v-html` to test if sidebar component can display the child component.

```
<div v-if="rightPanelOpen" class="right-panel" v-html="rightPanelComponent"></div>
```

the computed property (rightPanelComponent):

```
rightPanelComponent() {
    if( this.$store.state.boardRightPanel.component === false ) {
      return "<div style='display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; flex-grow: 1; height: 100%;'>Nothing found.</div>"
    } else {
      return this.$store.state.boardRightPanel.component
    }
  },
```

I am committing the child component in this way,

```
import About from '@/components/boards/post/About'

created() {
    document.title = 'loading ...'
    this.$store.commit( 'toggleRightPanel', true ) // This will show the sidebar
    this.$store.commit( 'rightPanelContent', About ) // This is where i am trying to send the child component for the sidebar

},
```

How i can display a child component in the sidebar in this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

Vue dynamic components use a **component** element with **is** attribute.
Note the binding syntax (:is="...").

***side-panel.vue***

```
<template>
  <component v-if="rightPanelComponent" :is="rightPanelComponent"></component>
  <div v-if="!rightPanelComponent" style='...'>Nothing found</div>
</template>

computed {
  rightPanelComponent() {
    return this.$store.state.boardRightPanel.componentTag
  }
}
```

Simplest is to declare all the component choices in main:

***main.js***

```
import About from '@/components/About.vue
import Another from '@/components/Another.vue

Vue.component('my-about', About)
Vue.component('my-another', Another)
```

but you can declare all possible child components locally in the side-panel:

***side-panel.vue***

```
import About from '@/components/About.vue
import Another from '@/components/Another.vue

components: {
    'my-about': About,
    'my-another': Another
}
```

***Parent.vue***

```
// Set the side-panel component here by storing the tag
this.$store.commit( 'rightPanelContent', 'my-about' )
```

Answer (score 0):

`v-html` is a preprocessed directive! The documentation says:

> Note that the contents are inserted as plain HTML - they will not be compiled as Vue templates. If you find yourself trying to compose templates using v-html, try to rethink the solution by using components instead. (https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-html).

My suggestion is that you create a component (https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html) and insert it into your rightPanelContent. The content for this component can be passed/controlled using props (https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Props).